# MS Word Picture Crop

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to know how to trim away the top, bottom, left, and right of a picture in Word to exact height and width.

I don't have Acrobat. I know I have done this in Word before - 9 or 10 years ago - but I don't remember how.

I have tried changing the width and height in the Crop feature on the Picture Format ribbon but that just makes the entire picture smaller or larger and does not trim away any of the picture. I can trim the picture using crop and the black bars but I don't want to do it freehand.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Office version you have, if you have any of the newer ones, with the ribbon menu at the top, select image (by clicking once on it) and look for the additional menu on top of the ribbon menu  (called Picture Tools). On the far right side is a square icon titled "Crop". Select it by clicking on it, then go to your image and trim by draging the edges (by holding down the left mouse button towards to the center of the image, making it visually smaller to the point you need it. Then you would use the hight and length values located on the right of the crop tool and select the desired sizes. Additionally, all options regading dimensions of an image are located on the bottom left corner of the section where crop and dimensions are located. Its a little square, which if clicked, pops up a windows with all the options.

Comment: Thank you!! I was hoping to be able to trim the picture more precisely than dragging the black bars. I remember being able to do this in Word 9 or 10 years ago. Perhaps it was a capability of the older version that wasn't carried over. As I drag the black bars, it does show the width and height, so it is possible to trim it to more exact dimensions that way. Thank you!

Comment: Okay. So, I decided to trim the picture freehand but use the Width and Height that appear when dragging the black bars to trim exactly what I wanted. However, when I did that the Width, for example, would jump from 10.35 to 10.37 when I wanted to trim to the 10.36 mark. Close enough, right? Well maybe...if I didn't have OCD. So I was determined to figure out how to trim to 10.36. And I did! But I was only able to trim the bottom and the right of the picture. Not the top or left. So I'll post another question. I started to post it here but I ran out of characters.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me in Microsoft Word 2013:

0. Paste or insert the image into your document.
1. Right-click and select “Format Picture…”. 
   A “Format Picture” panel will appear (on the right side of your window).
2. Click the fourth (last) icon, with hover-text “Picture”.
3. Adjust the “Width” and “Height” under “Crop position”
   to crop from the right and bottom.
   When you’ve gotten those where you want them,
4. Right-click the image and select “Size and Position…”.
5. Set “Rotation” to 180°.
6. Copy the image (e.g., right-click and select “Copy”).
7. Click somewhere else (e.g., the next line below the image)
   and do “Paste” → “Paste Special…” → “Paste as Picture (Enhanced Metafile)”. 
   (Some of the other options, e.g., “Bitmap”, might also work.)
8. Repeat steps 1-7.
9. Repeat steps 1-8 as many times as desired,
   but I expect that there is a risk that the image quality
   will degrade if you manipulate it too much.
10. Delete the unwanted copies of the image (all but the last).

Screenshots:

Before:

[image: Original, full-sized image]

After:

[image: Image cropped to exact dimensions]